# Parsing Date Time in different formats automatically in R

Tags: r, parsing, datetime

I have been working in R and  parsing Date Time using as.POSIXct with specific format strings. But today I noticed that as.POSIXct converted "8/1/2017 11:00:28 PM" into "2017-08-01 11:00:28" with format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M". The PM was not present in format and time were read wrongly since PM was not considered. Is this expected?

Is there a way in R to know if the parsing is done properly?

Also are there any R packages that can handle datetime in different formats & parse properly.

Comment: What is your system language? Can you check: Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")

Comment: I remember the `anytime` package, but I haven't used it yet... https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/anytime/index.html

Comment: Yes. it's expected. Seems clear from `?strptime` that you needed to use `format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p"` voting to close as a typo-equivalent (failure to read documentation).